# probability of solving at least one problem

Tags: probability

If P(A) is the probability of solving problem A . And P(B) is the probability of solving problem B. Then find probability of shocking at least one problem? In solution they have given that probability of least one is P(AUB) can anyone explain why? I am not understanding the reason . Thank you on advance

Comment: What do you think it should be?

Comment: I know that P(AUB)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A interaction B). But why is probability at least one=P(AUB)

Comment: This is true simply by definition. AUB *is* the event that at least one of A or B occurs. The *meaning* of P(AUB) is that it is the probability of at least one of A or  B occurring.

Comment: But if I see the meaning of p(AUB) in an example life that of dice the it would be equal to probabliy of both events together in the sample space. So how can it be used in at least one

Comment: I think that you misunderstand the meaning of U.

Comment: Solving both problems would be denoted as $A \cap B$ which is the "English equivalent" of 'A and B'.

Comment: Yes I also know that but why?? And U is union.

Comment: AUB  simply *is* the event that either A occurs or B occurs (hence at least one of them occurs). Your question is sort of like "how come you are using x + y to describe what happens when you add x and y?"

Comment: No my question is if P(AUB) means probability of both together (in case of problems like dice) how can it also be used for probablity of any one inthe above problem???

Comment: You are simply wrong when you say that "P(AUB) means probability of both together". You seem to be confusing union and intersection.

Comment: Ok then if I have a dice. In which event A is getting no 1 or 3 and event B is getting no 5or6 . Then P(A) is 1/3, and P(B)is also 1/3.if I consider a event c which isv getting 1,3,5,6 then c is similar to A and B together so P(c)=P(AUB).then in the problem of a student solving a problem for can we simply yes P(AUB) for P of at least solving one problem

Comment: "Get no 1 or 3" or "Get no 5 or 6".  Do I succeed at making at least one of those two phrases true by rolling a $1$?  Yes... the second phrase is true.  If B is true and I have the logical phrase "A or B", is the phrase true?  Yes, because at least one of them is true.  Your example, $P(A\cup B) = 1 \neq Pr(C)$ where $C$ is "not getting any of 1,3,5, or 6"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breaking this down in terms of set theory:

We consider an **experiment** which has observable **outcomes**.  The collection of all possible outcomes we call the **sample space**.  Here I will denote the sample space as $\Omega$.

An **event**, $A$, is a subset of the sample space.

---

$A\cup B$ is the *union* of the events $A$ and $B$.  It is defined as $A\cup B := \{x~|~x\in A~\text{or}~x\in B\}$, that is to say, it is the collection of all outcomes such that the outcome is in at least one of the events $A$ or $B$.  Colloquially, it can be understood as the English equivalent to "*or*."

$A\cap B$ is the *intersection* of the events $A$ and $B$.  It is defined as $A\cap B:= \{x~|~x\in A~\text{and}~x\in B\}$.  Colloquially, it can be understood as the English equivalent to "*and*."

---

Let us consider some examples:  Let our experiment be rolling a fair six-sided die and observing the number on the top face.  The set of possible outcomes is $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.  Let $A$ be the outcome "an odd number is rolled."  Let $B$ be the outcome "a number less than or equal to 3 is rolled."

We have in this scenario, $A=\{1,3,5\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3\}$

We have $A\cup B = \{1,2,3,5\}$ and $A\cap B = \{1,3\}$.

In English, $A\cup B$ here describes the event "an odd number is rolled **or** a number less than or equal to 3 is rolled"

$A\cap B$ here describes the event "a number is rolled which is both an odd number **and** less than or equal to 3"

---

Your example in the comments:  We roll a fair six-sided die and observe the number appearing on the top face.  The sample space is again $\Omega = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Letting $A$ be the event "The result is not a 1 or 3" and $B$ be the event "The result is not a 5 or 6."

One has $A = \{2,4,5,6\}$ and $B = \{1,2,3,4\}$

Here, the exact meaning of the English phrase gets muddied a bit.  $A\cup B$ is (The result is not a 1 or 3) *or* (The result is not a 5 or 6).  This is **not** logically equivalent to (The result is not a 1 or 3 or 5 or 6).  In fact, $A\cup B$, when looking at the actual outcomes present in each event, you will find is $A\cup B = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

On the other hand, $A\cap B$ is the phrase (The result is not a 1 or 3) *and* (The result is not a 5 or 6).  This is logically equivalent to the phrase (The result is not any of 1,3,5,6).  Looking at it based on the outcomes available, you see $A\cap B = \{2,4\}$

Your confusion seems to stem from trying place an "or" in the middle of a phrase with the word "not" preceding it.  DeMorgan's laws may help shed more light on this.

not(A) or not(B) is equivalent to not(A and B).  Worded another way, $A^c \cup B^c = (A\cap B)^c$.  Similarly, $A^c\cap B^c = (A\cup B)^c$

---

For your originally posted question, the very *interpretation* of $A\cup B$ in this case is the *event* that you get at least one of problem $A$ and problem $B$ right.  The probability of that occurring is denoted $P(A\cup B)$